# Error importing EXP_MEMBERS

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import EXP_MEMBERS but I get the following error:

> Static analysis:
>
> 2 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 3821)
>      76 values were expected, but found 6. (near "(" at position 3620)
>
> SQL query:
>
> INSERT INTO `exp_members` (`member_id`, `group_id`, `username`, `screen_name`, `password`, `salt`, `unique_id`, `crypt_key`, `authcode`, `email`, `url`, `location`, `occupation`, `interests`, `bday_d`, `bday_m`, `bday_y`, `aol_im`, `yahoo_im`, `msn_im`, `icq`, `bio`, `signature`, `avatar_filename`, `avatar_width`, `avatar_height`, `photo_filename`, `photo_width`, `photo_height`, `sig_img_filename`, `sig_img_width`, `sig_img_height`, `ignore_list`, `private_messages`, `accept_messages`, `last_view_bulletins`, `last_bulletin_date`, `ip_address`, `join_date`, `last_visit`, `last_activity`, `total_entries`, `total_comments`, `total_forum_topics`, `total_forum_posts`, `last_entry_date`, `last_comment_date`, `last_forum_post_date`, `last_email_date`, `in_authorlist`, `accept_admin_email`, `accept_user_email`, `notify_by_default`, `notify_of_pm`, `display_avatars`, `display_signatures`, `parse_smileys`, `smart_notifications`, `language`, `timezone`, `time_format`, `include_seconds`, `date_format`, `cp_theme`, `profile_theme`, `forum_theme`, `tracker`, `template_size`, `notepad`, `notepad_size`, `quick_links`, `quick_tabs`, `show_sidebar`, `pmember_id`, `rte_enabled`, `rte_toolset_id`) VALUES (4, 1, 'test@test', 'Nick Alder', 'b8a2664ef686d40d1f7c0d6124cb150bbc64a5ddd2b3a5ff53c39bc0e36bcc121f79ea7a941c9bf55d527d2c654f7733aa57c0cffe880ce8dbe1dd47117d40e6', 'ln''y[3?pEv?i7Q2J!K1XRZ.b|?~ZLeHj1X$0kO#jn''i~MR7#d9gPVq&n-oS7?&|T1y"KC?5[n,GBf%>Drq$EU)sK]i)C}6$n/*vS_^ez!KcTsit|bi[%n>^.^)\&BY,dVs%i-I7*,KO:Ri:C6m|:XypP-&$HblI#|FXPT,K{\SJVN[01Sfix\6J2&^h5?~aPwb3Hd8&Z\/3w;mf"2ttltgVpU@Re{]8vQtw2!$''7y&#x''1DB[b*P_;f8<#WtYDo3;J$f)XEKzOLCzMk2+4Ko[|#$2:r@b\', '44618e223d9854ba94161bb265cd4aa357de775b', 'f4085b33f0b9728ea4ac3e8322614b0b75286a31', NULL, 'test@test.com', '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 'y', 0, 0, '81.156.245.253', 1370811547, 1373841426, 1395876372, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'n', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'english', 'UTC', '24', 'n', '%j-%n-%y', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '20', NULL, '18', NULL, NULL, 'n', 0, 'y', 0), (14, 5, 'test@test.com', 'Mark Finnegan', '1a0f69354775a15816f98d864e2eef2c4e6ea4287700a7947a0d14687659b1b8b87545f130fda1be9bd69c9df5586a3678fd4fc89f37073660003f769cf7f758', '4zfd''~Q?-LOyI\
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''4zfd''~Q?-LOyI\' at line 5

The MySQL version I'm exporting from is 5.5.40-1.el6.remi, and the version I'm importing into is 5.5.44-30.el6.art. Would this cause a problem?

EE version is the same on both systems as I'm replicating a site (v2.8.1).

All other tables have imported OK. I can import some individual rows in the MEMBERS table, but others throw this error.

Comment: What the full string that is started from '4zfd''~Q?-LOyI\' ? Because if it is ended as \' - it could escape last ' and brake query.

Comment: That wasn't the full string - just the error output. Turns out I could import members in small batches of 2-10 a time. Not sure why this would be. The same members would cause errors if I tried to import larger batches...